# Optimized way to find this integer solution greater than a certain value?

Tags: optimization, modular-arithmetic, integer-programming

So, this comes from a programming problem, but it is math that I feel like should be easy, that I just can't figure out a quick way to do, short of writing a python script. It's an optimization problem, so maybe calculus could help me, but I need integer solutions, and I wouldn't know how to apply calculus to that.

I'm trying to write an assembly language program which delays the CPU for exactly `n` ms. The CPU is running at 16 MHz, and I have written an inner loop which delays for 160 cycles. It is called repeatedly by an outer loop which has an overhead of 2 cycles. So, each time the out loop runs, it delays the CPU by 162 cycles.

The CPU also has overhead of 12 cycles to account for additional needed instructions. So, I need the inner loop to run for 15,988 cycles. I can modify the outer loop to include additional instructions which delay the CPU by 1 cycle each, but the keep the routine short, I want to minimize the number of instructions for this.

In other words, if $x=162$ is the number of cycles the loop takes, $\Delta{x}$ is the amount of cycles I add to the loop, and $15,988 \mod{(x+\Delta{x})} =n$, I'd like to minimize $\Delta{x} + n$

How can I efficiently solve this, without just writing a program to iterate through each x and check the remainder?

(We're just gonna pretend we live in a perfect world where all CPU's run exactly at their advertised clock speed and hardware interrupts never happen)

Comment: $15988$ is divisible by prime $571$ which is greater than $\sqrt{15988} <130$ (so other factors will be below your minimum). So $(15988 \bmod 571)=0$.

Comment: This is a nice upper bound, but I'd like to try and get closer

Comment: What is your acceptable range for $(15988 \bmod x)$ then?

Comment: I just edited my question, I realized I was unclear

Comment: I'd estimate 10 or 15 for minimum value of 15988 mod x. The result of that expression gives me the number of lines of code I'll need to delay with, so I'd like to keep it low. In other words, I'd like to know the minimum amount I need to increase x by to have the lowest remainder. So, I'd like to keep the increase of x below around 15 and the remainder lower than the same.

Comment: In other words, I can add lines to the loop to make the loop run longer, or I can add lines after the loop to make up for the remainder. I'd like to keep the sum of these two values, the remainder, and the amount I add to x, at a minimum. Is this clearer?

Comment: I edited the question once again, I believe it now explains accurately what I need.

Comment: Looking at the factors of the numbers just less than $15988$, I see $219$ divides $15987$. So $(15988\bmod 219)=1 $

Comment: 219 produces a good low value for the remainder, but results in a high value of $\Delta{x}$. I'd like to minimize the sum of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you don't need to search many numbers to minimize $\Delta x + n$.

$(15988 \bmod 162) = 112$, so you won't need to have $\Delta x >112$ .

Then $(15988 \bmod 163) = 14$, giving $\Delta x + n=15$. This limits the search even more - we won't need to check any value above $162+15 = 177$.

And in fact no better value of  $\Delta x + n$ occurs in that range. $170 = 162+8$ is close with $(15988 \bmod 170) = 8$ and $\Delta x + n =16$, which might be useful if $\Delta x =1$ turns out to be too small.

Comment: These numbers are higher than I'd like, but the world doesn't always work out that nicely I guess, lol. Your help is greatly appreciated. I really like your approach to narrowing in on the solution. I think I learned something here.

Comment: Wait, isn't 15,988 mod 162 = 112?

Comment: Yes, typo corrected. I didn't give that value much attention after $163$ changed the limits so significantly.